# Is there a faster way to traverse your Outbound Changeset?

Tags: deployment, change-set

So I have an outbound changeset that contains more than 350 components. Now the changeset list only shows 25 components at one time and it would take me a million years to traverse all the way to the back of the list if I want to remove a component starting with the letter 'Z'.

As such, I just want to ask, is there a faster way to traverse the outbound changeset list?

Thanks.

EDIT:
A follow-up question. IS there also a faster way to remove components on a changeset when said components are far on the back of the list? Thanks.

Comment: One thing i have used is change set booster : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-change-set-tur/dlcjllapchpeedkecmhfnpfenpbglioo?hl=en